# Fetch data from firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> Not able to fetch the data it gives "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()".Not Able to find any solution please help.

The Code is

```
    public class AdminUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv1,tv2;
   private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_user);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String username=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(username);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);


       mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           // String name=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                String name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class).toString() ;
                String address=dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class).toString();
                tv1.setText(name);
                tv2.setText(address);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 2 lines:

```
String name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class).toString() ;
String address=dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class).toString();
```

are causing your problem, go to the Firebase documentation and read about how to read data from the realtime database here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

**Edit**
To give you an example specific to your question, first you need to create a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) class that represent the data you have in your database, for example.

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String address;

public User() {
    //Empty constructor required by firebase 
    // serialize the data retrieved and convert
    // it to an object of this class
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Then in your valueEventListener you can do something like this

```
      mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           //Serialize your retrieved data to a User object
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            //Now you have an object of the User class and can use its getters like this
            tv1.setText(user.getName());
            tv2.setText(user.getAddress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I use getKey in place of getValue here the key is printed successfully but value at that key is not there after apllying getValue.

Comment: It is because you're applying the getValue method incorrectly, please refer to the documentation.

Comment: Sir I can't understand from that docs.If you provide some help it will be benificial for me.

Comment: Actually i used something different i can't checked this but its okk.Nd I have another problem related to recyclerview can you please resolve it

Comment: can you please answer this firebase related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46556028/6144372